# Using simple GUI in OpenCV Dlib XCode project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I am making a C++ project where I need to show the images with certain points in a GUI.

Till here its simple using `highGUI` but problem happens with my next requirements.

I need to use the points drawn in the GUI and drag it to some other point and get that point.
I know openCV doesn't support this much requirements in GUI, so what other options are left to me?

One option that I see is using `QT`, also is it possible for me to use Objective C window `.xib` and use it together with my c++ project?

PS : HighGUI does take mouse input, but what I want is to create a point and drag it to some other point in the GUI window and then get the coordinate.

Comment: you can try [this demo program](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sturkmen72/opencv/8bb3863f529e381bc67e477a84c2f451e5cd1c2d/samples/cpp/warpPerspective_demo.cpp). it will give an idea dragging points

Comment: @sturkmen Done only using openCV?

Comment: yes, you can try it. if you have any appreciation also take a look [at new demo PR](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9317). you can mention your opinion about the PR.

Comment: The points are not giving me dragging points in the GUI, that is the main problem I am facing.

Comment: I'd recommend using QT for this. You can create a mouse event and link it to actions. This is quite common in CAD applications.

Comment: @pds I haven't used QT before. Can you please guide me to the correct resources which I can use for this purpose.

Comment: @arqam: See https://github.com/eryar/occQt

Comment: @pds That's a project right. I meant, resource to use QT directly, like in my case what should I use, widget, frameworks etc.

Comment: @arqam OpenCV uses an OpenGL buffer. Thus, you'll need to look into QApplication, QMainWindow and QGLWidget.